# Simon Says button color won't return to normal after button press

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-handler, postdelayed

```
public void flashButton(int color) {
    final ImageView colors = findViewById(R.id.buttonsImage);
    final int newColor = color;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(newColor == 1)
                colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_activated_png);
            if(newColor == 2)
                colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_activated_png);
            if(newColor == 3)
                colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_activated_png);
            if(newColor == 4)
                colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_activated_png);

            System.out.println("Flashed color: " + newColor);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

    colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_buttons);
    System.out.println("Returned Color.");
}
```

The button color is being changed for each button with R.drawable.green_activated_png). Then, I'm changing it back with (R.drawable.normal_buttons). I'm thinking my problem is in handler.postDelayed(r, 1000). But the color ins't changing back to normal after the user presses the correct color.

Comment: No, you've got it backwards: you're executing the last two lines, i.e. normal, immediately, and then queueing up r to run after a second.

Comment: Also rather than the four ifs you could e.g. make an array of resource IDs and then just look up the resource ID from that array based on newColour, and e.g. put the normal_buttons value in as 0. And you should be using [`Log.d()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or similar rather than println. And I thought the game was just ["Simon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game)) - "Simon Says" is something else?

Comment: Oh, and you could have declared your argument 'final int color' to have a final variable for the closure rather than having to copy it into newColor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are kind of doing it in just opposite.You have to change the color of `Button` immediately after pressing it and you will have to keep your returned color into `postDelayed` so that after the delay of given time it turns into normal color.

```
public void flashButton(int color) {
    final ImageView colors = findViewById(R.id.buttonsImage);
    final int newColor = color;
    if(newColor == 1)
        colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_activated_png);
    if(newColor == 2)
        colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_activated_png);
    if(newColor == 3)
        colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_activated_png);
    if(newColor == 4)
        colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_activated_png);
    System.out.println("Flashed color: " + newColor);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_buttons);
            System.out.println("Returned Color.");
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank You for the detailed and helpful reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the flow of the function is incorrect. Because post delay method execute after 1 second. Before that colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_buttons) method will be executed. Change the flow as below

```
public void flashButton(int color) {
final ImageView colors = findViewById(R.id.buttonsImage);
final int newColor = color;
        if(newColor == 1)
            colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_activated_png);
        if(newColor == 2)
            colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_activated_png);
        if(newColor == 3)
            colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_activated_png);
        if(newColor == 4)
            colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_activated_png);

Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        colors.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_buttons);
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```